# Twitter app that doesn't require an account

Tags: android

I'm looking for a twitter app for quickly reading tweets, without needing an account. I've tried a few apps but they refuse to go any further without an account. I figure that since I can browse the webpage on my PC without an account, why should I need one on my phone?

Ideally, the client would be:

- Lightweight/fast
- Free
- For Android
- Be able to save people I "follow" or have favourites

I've tried using the mobile twitter site, but it keeps popping up fullscreen nag prompts asking me to login/sign up. The favourites thing may be more difficult but RedReader (android reddit client) allows saving subreddits without needing an account so it's probably not impossible.

Comment: Like on your PC, you could use the browser on Android as well?

Comment: The mobile site is OK, but not very customisable, it has the annoying full screen nag prompts and requires me to fire up a browser.

Comment: I see. But I very much doubt any Twitter client will work without account details. All I can give you is a [link to my list of Twitter apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_twitter) to check with, while waiting for answers. Good luck then!